OneToMany/ManyToOne relation problem: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
So I have already made some things in Spring Boot with Java and mysql as the relational database. I recently switched to Kotlin due to an assignment of one of my teachers. Sadly I am facing issues when trying to make a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship between two classes. The annotations used worked in my recent Java project so I don't know what could lead to this problem.
These are the classes I'm using (I shortened away the body as it is pretty much empty):
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = PropertyGenerator::class,
    property = "id",
    scope = Game::class
)
class Game (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id : Long = 0,
    @Column(name = "players", nullable = false)
    var players : Int = 2,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var splitCards : Int = 0,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var pointsI : Int = 0,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var pointsD : Int = 0,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var stichsI : Int = 0,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var stichsD : Int = 0,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var insets : Int = 2,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var tableName : String = "",
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var insetsPerGame : Int = 4,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var nickNamePlayerI : String = "",
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var nickNamePlayerD : String = "",
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var rounds : Set<Round> = HashSet()
)

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = PropertyGenerator::class,
    property = "id",
    scope = Round::class
)
class Round (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id : Long = 0,
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "round_cardsI", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "id")])
    @Column(name = "cardsI")
    var cardsI : Set<Card> = HashSet(),
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "round_cardsD", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "id")])
    @Column(name = "cardsD")
    var cardsD : Set<Card> = HashSet(),
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    var game : Game = Game(),
)

These are the logs I get when I try to start the application:
2024-04-07T14:50:24.924Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'org.adunkaf01.watten.models.Game'
........
2024-04-07T14:50:25.045Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'org.adunkaf01.watten.models.Game'

I would be very happy if someone spots the issue in my code and could help me out.
